# DoublyLinkedList for node.js

Tags: javascript, array, linked-list, node.js

What do you think guys?

```
module.exports = CDoublyLinkedList = function CDoublyLinkedList() {
    this._size = 0;

    this.first = undefined;
    this.last = undefined;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.iterator = function(data) {
    return new this.CIterator(this);
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.size = function(data) {
    return this._size;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.push = function(data) {
    var item = new this.CItem();
    item.data = data;

    if ( this._size == 0 ) {
        this.first = this.last = item;
    }
    else {
        item.prev = this.last;
        item.prev.next = item;
        this.last = item;
    }

    this._size++;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.pop = function() {
    if ( this._size == 0 ) {
        return undefined;
    }

    var poped = this.last;
    this.last = this.last.prev;

    this._size--;

    return poped;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.unshift = function(data) {
    var item = new this.CItem();
    item.data = data;

    if ( this._size == 0 ) {
        this.first = this.last = item;
    }
    else {
        item.next = this.first;
        this.first = item;
    }

    this._size++;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.shift = function() {
    if ( this._size == 0 ) {
        return undefined;
    }

    var shifted = this.first;
    this.first = this.first.next;

    this._size--;

    return shifted;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype._getSet = function(index, value) {
    if ( index < 0 ) return undefined;

    var i = 0;
    var next = this.first;

    while(next) {
        if ( i === index ) return (value ? (next.data = value) : next.data);

        next = next.next;
        i++;
    }

    return undefined;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.get = function(index) {
    return this._getSet(index);
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.set = function(index, value) {
    return this._getSet(index, value);
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.remove = function(data) {
    var curr = this.first;

    while(curr) {
        if ( curr.data === data ) {
            curr.removed = true;

            if ( this.first === curr ) this.first = curr.next;
            if ( this.last === curr ) this.last = curr.prev;

            if ( curr.prev ) curr.prev.next = curr.next;
            if ( curr.next ) curr.next.prev = curr.prev;

            this._size--;

            return true;
        }

        curr = curr.next;
    }

    return false;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.toString = function(fn) {
    var curr = this.first;
    var str = "CDoublyLinkedList(";

    while(curr) {
        if ( fn ) str += fn(curr.data);
        else str += JSON.stringify(curr.data);

        if ( curr != this.last ) str += ",";

        curr = curr.next;
    }

    return str + ")";
}

// ######################################################################### CItem

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CItem = function CItem() {
    this.prev = undefined;
    this.next = undefined;

    this.data = undefined;

    this.removed = false;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CItem.prototype.prev = function() { return this.prev; }
CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CItem.prototype.next = function() { return this.next; }
CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CItem.prototype.data = function() { return this.data; }
CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CItem.prototype.clear = function() { this.prev = this.next = this.data = undefined; }

// ######################################################################### CIterator

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CIterator = function CIterator(list) {
    this.list = list;

    this.current = undefined;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CIterator.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.current = undefined;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CIterator.prototype.copyState = function(iterator) {
    if ( iterator.list !== this.list ) throw new Error("CIterator list mismatch");
    this.current = iterator.current;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CIterator.prototype.next = function() {
    if ( !this.current ) {
        if ( !this.list.first ) return;
        else {
            this.current = this.list.first;
            return this.current.data;
        }
    }
    else {
        this.current = this.current.next;
        if ( this.current ) {
            if ( this.current.removed ) return this.next();
            return this.current.data;
        }
    }

    return;
}

CDoublyLinkedList.prototype.CIterator.prototype.prev = function() {
    if ( !this.current ) {
        if ( !this.list.last ) return;
        else {
            this.current = this.list.last;
            return this.current.data;
        }
    }
    else {
        this.current = this.current.prev;
        if ( this.current ) {
            if ( this.current.removed ) return this.prev();
            return this.current.data;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LGTM, the only nit I would have is using `===` for comparing `this._size` to 0 for extreme type safety.

I didn't test for functionality, but I assume that by posting here, you've tested it and everything works.